# Paint leaking through new paint

Tags: paint

I have been trying to paint the walls of a room in my house. Unfortunately for whatever strange reason, the old paint the tenants of my house used before has bled through every layer of paint I have tried. (For context, it’s a few avengers murals including a huge mural of hulk) I have no idea what to do to cover it and I have no clue what kind of paint would cause this type of excessive bleeding through. We’ve covered it in a layer of white primer, black primer, and when the black primer seemed to work, covered it with the final layer of paint we wanted. But now that it’s been a few months it’s starting to bleed through all those layers again. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The cure is to use shellac-based primer. See the question linked above and my answer. The stuff is a life saver when all else fails.